# How do I make well separated mirrored histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have this RData [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m0h81ina4wfegj/rdata.rdata?dl=0). I want to plot a mirrored histogram that looks like this [figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0igimnhkniynqgx/Screenshot.png?dl=0) where each line is well separated. I have these codes below which seems to work, but the lines are clumped together and are not well separated. How can I separate the lines? I did try all these options:

```
"p" for points,
"l" for lines,
"b" for both,"p" for points,
"h" for 'histogram' like
```

Additionally, I also want to add plus and minus above and below zero respectively as shown in the example figure.

Here is my code:

```
load("rdata.rdata")
# Now plot
tiff(
  filename = paste0("Mirrored plot of ", sample.name) ,
  width = 4,
  height = 2,
  pointsize = 6,
  units = 'in',
  res = 300
)

plot(
  pos$coverage,
  type = 'h',
  # type= 's',
  ylim = c(-20, 20),
  # col='blue',
  col = 'deepskyblue2',
  # ylab=expression ("Number of aligned reads" ~ (10^-3)),
  ylab = "",
  xlab = paste0("Aligned with ", aligned.with),
  xaxt = 'n',
  # main=paste0("Coverage of mapped " , sample.name," reads")
  # ylab to re-align the y-axis legend
)
title(
  ylab = expression ("Number of aligned reads" ~ (10 ^ -3)),
  line = 2,
  cex.lab = 1.2,
  family = "Calibri Light"
)

# plot the coverage on the negative strand
#neg coverage ; getting (10^-3) so easy to plot

lines(neg$coverage,
      type = 'h',
      # type='s',
      # col='red'
      col = 'darkorange3')


l <- length(pos$position)
axis(1,
     at = floor (seq(
       from = 1, to = l, by = l / 10
     )),
     labels = floor (seq(
       from = head(pos$position, n = 1) - 0,
       to = tail(pos$position, n = 1),
       by = l / 10
     )))
dev.off()
```

Comment: @Sathish That doesn;t help. Also, I am using base plot function.

Comment: likely to do with the dimensions/resolution of your device and/or the width of your lines. you can use `cairo_pdf` instead of a tiff so you won't lose image quality

Comment: Please don't link data at all, or images from dropbox: when the links die, this question becomes much less valuable (if not useless). Please use SO's internal mechanism for uploading images (goes through imgur.com), and please use something like `dput(head(x,n=10))` for providing *usable data*.